# Absoluteness and Extensionality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, model-theory

In the set theory text that I am reading, the author writes:

> Relative to the set $A = \{ 0, \{\{0\}\} \}$, the sets $0$ and $\{\{0\}\}$ are indistinguishable in the sense that $[$for all $x$ in $A$, $x$ is a member of $0$ just in case it is a member of $\{\{0\}\}]$, so $[0 = \{\{0\}\}]$ restricted to $A$ is true but $[0 = \{\{0\}\}]$ "restricted" to $V$ is not.

I don't understand the first statement.  Why is $0 = \{\{0\}\}$ not false in $A$ even though "$x$ is an element of $0$ just in case it is an element of $\{\{0\}\}$" is true there?  (Isn't the truth-condition for "$x = y$" that the thing assigned to $x$ is the numerically same thing as that assigned to $y$?)  Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$0 = \{\{0\}\}$` shows $0 = \{\{0\}\}$. More formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky explanation. Let's say that two sets $a, b$ are $\in$-equivalent if they satisfy $\forall x(x\in a\leftrightarrow x\in b) $.

The axiom of extensionality states that two $\in$-equivalent sets are actually equal.

But what happens if we only look at $A$ as in the question? Now the quantifier on $x$ is only allowed to go over elements of $A$. So now the two sets $0, \{\{0\}\}$ are $\in$-equivalent ***as far as $A$ is concerned***. Namely $A$ "knows" these are two different objects, but it doesn't "know" how to separate them using only the $\in$ relation.

So in the structure $(A, \in)$ the axiom of extensionality fails.

Comment: +1. @OP, it might be helpful to forget your intuitions about set theory, and think of the structures $(V, \in)$ (the whole set-theoretic universe) and $(A, \in)$ (the smaller piece you're looking at) just as directed graphs: nodes are objects, and an arrow from $a$ to $b$ means "$a\in b$." Then - relative to $A$! - both $\{\{0\}\}$ and $0$ have the property that "no vertex has an arrow pointing to me." (For some reason, I find this shift in language very clarifying; of course your mileage may vary.)

Comment: Thanks, both.  But I took the quote to be saying that Extensionality *remains true* in the structure (A,∈).  My confusion was precisely that it doesn't seem to (since some "∈ -equivalent" sets are not equal, to use Asaf's term).  Perhaps I misread the quote?  Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding you?  To be clear: Extensionality fails in (A,∈), yes?

Comment: @davidp: What is the name of the text? Have you looked for an errata?

Comment: Another option, which also might be clearer if the name of the book was known, is that the logic there is without equality and the definition of equality is the extensionality axiom.

Comment: The book is Sheppard _The Logic of Infinity_.  I think I might have already caught a few errors, so perhaps I'll compile them all and send them the author.  I intend to read much of the book in the next couple of weeks.  (In the second case you mention -- if = abbreviates the claim about membership -- wouldn't Extensionality be trivially absolute?)

Comment: (And, yes, I found the errata, but this problem is not mentioned.)

Comment: @davidp: Well, in the second case it would be but equality wouldn't. Which seems to be what it's saying.

Comment: Yes, thanks again.

Comment: @davidp: Sheppard writes *"We could present ZF in this way, however we prefer to introduce equality as a defined relation, making use of membership."* (p. 234), so I'm guessing that my "second case" is right on the money there.

Comment: Wow!  I never even thought to check.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Extensionality ($E$) is $\forall a\;\forall b \; (a=b\iff (\forall x\; (x\in a \iff x \in b))).$ Now relativized to $A$ we have $E^A\iff \forall a\in A\;\forall b\in A\; (b=a\iff (\forall x\in A\; (x\in a\iff x\in b))).$ Now no member of $A$ belongs to $0$ and no member of $A$ belongs to $\{\{0\}\}.$ So if $E^A$ were true we would have $0=\{\{0\}\},$ which is absurd by the def'n of $0$. It is not correct to say that "$0=\{\{0\}\}$ is true in A". It is correct to say that $A$ does not satisfy $E.$